# Mathjax stops rendering after initiating custom widget in Jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, mathjax, ipywidgets

I am having an issue of MathJax failing to render LateX in my Jupyter Notebook after (not before) initiating a custom ipywidget based widget, in this case an html based table widget.  This includes in the Markdown cells, not just python generated output.

I am not trying to render any LateX in the table and have no MathJax calls in the widget javascript and, though the widget itself appears to work perfectly, it disables/kills any MathJax rendering afterward (requiring a Jupyter restart).  Other ipywidgets standard widgets do not effect MathJax operation.  There are also no errors reported by the notebook when instantiating the widget.

I am running the same Python Jupyter notebook on Windows 7 with Pip install and on MacOS 10.12.3 with a Macports install.  The problem is not present on my Mac using Safari, only on the Windows 7 system using either FireFox or Internet Explorer.

Windows7: Jupyter-notebook 4.4.1, Python 2.7.10

MacOS 10.12.3: Jupyter-notebook 4.3.1, Python 2.7.13

Unfortunately, I am not well enough versed in MathJax to further diagnose the issue or generate a short enough snippet of code to reproduce the problem that can be shared.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Without a sample, it will be difficult to help.